# Where is the flaw in my logic for finding all the coordinates whose center is covered by a square

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

.. a square whose opposite ends are given by (x1,y1), (x3, y3).

For example, see the image

[image]

(x1,y1)=(2,6), (x3,y3)=(8,4)

I'm thinking in terms of basic "y = mx + b" Algebra 1 stuff.

```
public void DrawSquare(double x1, double y1, double x3, double y3)
{
    // Increment input coordinates so that they now are
    // at the center of the squares
    x1 += 0.5;
    y1 += 0.5;
    x3 += 0.5;
    y3 += 0.5;

    // Ensure x1 <= x2
    if(x1 > x3)
    {
        SwapDoubles(ref x1, ref x3);
        SwapDoubles(ref y1, ref y3);
    }

    // Get midpoints of x-y pairs
    double midx = (x1 + x3) / 2;
    double midy = (y1 + y3) / 2;

    // Get the two lines f(x) = m1*x + b1 and g(x) = m3*x + b2
    // that parallel the sides of the square and run through the center.
    double m = (y3 - y1) / (x3 - x1);
    if (m == 0)
        m = double.Epsilon; // better way to do this?
    double m1 = -m;
    double m3 = 1 / m;
    double b1 = midy - m1 * midx;
    double b3 = midy - m3 * midx;

    // Get distance from center to lines that run across the sides of the square
    double d = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((double)x1 - midx, 2) + Math.Pow((double)y1 - midy, 2)) / Math.Sqrt(2);

    DrawInRange((Coordinate<int> coord) =>
    {
        // distance from middle of coordinate to line 1
        double d1 = ClosestDistanceToLine(m1, b1, coord.X + 0.5, coord.Y + 0.5);
        // distance from middle coordinate to line 2
        double d2 = ClosestDistanceToLine(m3, b3, coord.X + 0.5, coord.Y + 0.5);
        return  d1 <= d && d2 <= d;
    });
}

// finds the closest distance beteen the line y = mx + b and the point (x0, y0)
// http://www.intmath.com/plane-analytic-geometry/perpendicular-distance-point-line.php
static double ClosestDistanceToLine(double m, double b, double x0, double y0)
{
    double A = m;
    double B = -1;
    double C = b;
    double numerator = Math.Abs(A * x0 + B * y0 + C);
    double denominator = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(A, 2.0) + Math.Pow(B, 2.0));
    return  numerator / denominator;
}
```

Any idea why this isn't getting the proper coordinates for me?

Comment: missing SwapDoubles?

Comment: Is the "+ 0.5" really necessary? And what do you mean by "proper coordinates"? What is the expected and what the actual output?